# Continuous, Non-analytic function with maximum on the interior of a compact set?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Is there an example of a complex function on a compact set K that is continuous, non-analytic, and achieves its maximum on int(K)?

Since the max mod principle says that if the function is analytic, then the maximum is on the boundary. I'm looking for a non-analytic function where the maximum is not on the boundary, but the function is continuous.

Comment: $-|z|$ on the closed unit disk.

Comment: This is an interesting question from the motivational point of view. Ordinarily, it should be obvious that there are sufficiently well-behaved functions on a plane which can have their maxima wherever they want. Just imagine the graph of their modulus as a hilly landscape, which can look like whatever if it only needs continuity. The maximum modulus principle for analytic functions should then come as a big surprise, since it's a *huge* restriction for analytic functions, which even smooth functions can completely ignore.

Comment: Can you think of a real function on an interval which has maximum/minimum   at an interior point? The complex case is no different.

Comment: thanks. i had a suspicion there was a simple example but I was blanking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any compact set $K \subset \Bbb C$ with nonempty interior and $a \in \operatorname{int}(K)$, the function $f(z) = -|z-a|$ is such an example.

There is nothing special about the complex numbers here, the same example works on any metric space $(X, d)$ with $f(x) = -d(x, a)$ for some $a \in \operatorname{int}(K)$.